# flowers_tf_lite.ipynb - Train the model

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I was testing the sample notebook at [flowers_tf_lite.ipynb](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/community/en/flowers_tf_lite.ipynb#scrollTo=RxvgOYTDSWTx) and when I get to training cell it doesn't run.

It seems like it's always at infinity

[Train the model - Unknown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J885T.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Pedro Asseiro Actually, an iterator generates data dynamically. So the length of a dataset iterator is unknown until you iterate through it at least once. You could pass steps_per_epoch argument to the `model.fit_generator` as shown below. Then, it prints as you are expecting.

```
with tf.device("/device:GPU:0"):
  history = model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=len(train_generator),
                    epochs=epochs, 
                    validation_data=val_generator,validation_steps=len(val_generator))
```

### Edit 1:

@Pedro Asseiro @gokul_uf I update the above code based on your comments. You need to add `steps_per_epoch` as well as `validation_steps`.  Another change I made was running `model.fit` under GPU. Moreover, I did exactly same thing to `model.fit` under fine tuning section.

```
with tf.device("/device:GPU:0"):
  history_fine = model.fit_generator(train_generator, steps_per_epoch=len(train_generator),
                         epochs=5,
                         validation_data=val_generator,validation_steps=len(val_generator))
```

Please check the [GitHub gist here](https://github.com/jvishnuvardhan/Stackoverflow_Questions/blob/master/flowers_tf_lite.ipynb). Thanks!

Please let me know if anything is not working. Thanks!

Comment: If you are using recent Tensorflow like `2.1` or `2.2`, then you can replace `model.fit_generator` with `model.fit` as it was deprecated. Thanksj!

Comment: I tested this option, but the program only runs the first epoch and then remains in an infinite loop, it doesn't run

Comment: The above code results in another bug that comes from the TF library. So this doesn't work on the notebook either

Comment: @Pedro Asseiro I update the code above, and also pointed to the gist I am sharing. With those modifications, code runs much faster than what you experienced earlier without those modifications. Hope it helps you both and others. Thanks!

Comment: @gokul_uf Can you please check the gist shared above and let me know where you are facing another error. Please check the updated code so that it run fast for you. Thanks!

Comment: We don't need `with tf.device("/device:GPU:0")` for this example as the colab runtime is already using GPU in that example. I wanted to keep it here so that everyone know they can run some of the ops on a select device. If we don't define, Tensorflow will figure out which ops to run under GPU and CPU.

Comment: @PedroAsseiro If my answer helped you, then please upvote it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is actually running, the `Unknown` that you see is because `fit_generator` doesn't seem to figure out how many batches are in the Dataset. I tried using `steps_in_epoch` argument in `fit_from_generator` which throws other issues related to the library.

A work-around would be to manually stop the training when you think the performance is good enough and continue with the rest of the notebook. You can stop the current execution by pressing the "Stop" button on the top-left of the cell or from the Runtime Menu.

Comment: If I stop manually the code follows does not find the variable 'history'

Comment: The `history` variable is only used to display the training curves. You can skip that cell without much issue